# send and print array values with post

Tags: php

Why my ECHO doesn't print the value 1 ?

```
<dl><input type='checkbox' class='tinyField' name="informTktUpdate['hd']" value="1" /> Inform user by email</dl>
<dl><input type='checkbox' class='tinyField' name="informTktUpdate['prog']" value="1"  /> Inform programmer by email</dl>

echo ($_POST['informTktUpdate']['prog']);
```

if I'm using "print_r(($_POST['informTktUpdate'])" i get:

```
 Array ( ['hd'] => 1 ['prog'] => 1 )
```

Comment: have you got `<?PHP ?>` tags to wrap the code?

Comment: yes @mithunsatheesh
...............

Comment: Is the form submitted with `post`?

Comment: yes @mudasobwa   -> <form method='post'....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

remove the quotes around array keys in HTML parts.
it have to be

```
<input type='checkbox' class='tinyField' name="informTktUpdate[hd]" value="1" />
```